# Estiver ou Tiver?

Tags: gramática

Preciso saber qual dos dois usar na seguinte frase:

> Todos os itens em que o Grupo Impr. **Estiver/Tiver** preenchido com a letra ( A )
>   vão imprimir na mesma comanda. Mesmo estando em grupos separados.

Comment: Esse "Grupo Impr." é extremamente confuso, pelo que não dá para entender que se trata de uma opção que pode ser preenchida num formulário.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estou considerando que você esteja falando dos itens com o campo "Grupo" preenchido com A (na versão original da pergunta, faltava  *em* para a frase ficar correta: *Todos os itens **em** que o Grupo ...*). E com isso você usa *estiver*, que vem do verbo *estar*. *Tiver* vem do verbo *ter*, que não faria sentido nessa frase. Experimente substituir por *esteja* ou *tenha* que fica bem claro:

- *Todos os itens em que o Grupo Impr. **esteja** preenchido com a letra ( A ) vão imprimir na mesma comanda. Mesmo estando em grupos separados.*
- *Todos os itens em que o Grupo Impr. **tenha** preenchido com a letra ( A ) vão imprimir na mesma comanda. Mesmo estando em grupos separados.* (não faz sentido, certo?)

Comment: Ahhhhh sim, entendi agora... Vlw!

Comment: @Marcos Eu não! O bfaravetto introduziu um _em_ que não está na frase original. Deveria estar? Não percebo patavina do contexto. Mas em geral é _Todos os itens **em que** o Grupo **esteja** preenhcido_, mas _Todos os itens **que** o Grupo **tenha** preenchido_

Comment: Tem razão @Jacinto, eu não tinha me dado conta de que o tenha fazia sentido sem o ***em***. Introduzi por considerar que estava faltando, mas como também não sei o que é o tal "Grupo Impr.", ambas as interpretações são possíveis.

Comment: Oh, percebi isso agora!

Comment: Grupo Impr. é uma opção... que você marca o "Check" se quiser ativá-la ou não.

Comment: Mas eu não vejo problema no acréscimo do "em"... Então vou deixar como resposta certa mesmo assim.

Comment: @MarcosSartorato Você entendeu a diferença de sentido? Com *em que ... esteja*, estamos falando que o tal grupo é que estaria preenchido. Sem o *em*, em *que ... tenha*, o grupo é quem preenche (preenche todos os itens). A frase muda totalmente de sentido.

Comment: Sim, eu entendi. No caso aqui, quando o Grupo Impr. estiver preenchido com a letra (A), todos os itens serão imprimidos na mesma comanda...

Comment: Ou seja, esta resposta afirma que tem de ser com o verbo "estar" para uma frase ligeiramente, mas crucialmente, alterada. Como é possível a comunidade estar a aceitá-la?

Comment: @E_net4 A frase precisava ser alterada por um erro de regência do próprio autor da pergunta. Minha resposta está de acordo com a intenção dele.

Comment: Então que a própria pergunta seja modificada também. Senão, há obviamente um conflito entre a pergunta e a resposta.

Comment: @E_net4 Melhorou?

Comment: @E_net4 Introduzi lá o "em" na pergunta. Para alguma coisa hão-de servir os poderes especiais.

Comment: @Jacinto Mas isso invalidou parcialmente ambas as respostas...

Comment: @Marcos A resposta do Centaurus fica compreensível, porque "tal como a frase foi postada" continua  fazer sentido e ele tem as frases completas. A tua fica mais confusa. Vejo duas possibilidades: voltar à versão anterior da pergunta ou tu adaptares a tua resposta. Posso deixar a decisão e ação correspondente ao teu cuidado? Mas acho que a situação anterior é pouco satisfatória.

Comment: @Jacinto ok eu me viro. PS: meu nome não é Marcos :P

Comment: Bem sei. Mas tu és avisado do meu comentário por seres o autor do post, e eu achei boa ideia avisar também o autor da pergunta.

Comment: Certo! Obrigado pela resposta :p A do Centaurus também ficou muito boa mas essa me esclareceu melhor! E sim, tudo bem em ter mudado a pergunta xD

Answer (score 4):

**Da forma que a frase foi postada** "Todos os itens que o Grupo Impr.___________ preenchido com a letra A"

- Se usarmos "tiver preenchido" significa que o **"Grupo Impr preencheu"**, Grupo Impr é o sujeito de preencheu. E a frase está gramaticalmente correta.
- Se usarmos "estiver", teremos que embutir a preposição "em" antes de "que"  (**em que** o Grupo Impr.) e o significado muda.  **"Todos os itens em que o Grupo Impr está preenchido com a letra A"**, e o agente da passiva não é citado.
- **Se não usarmos  a preposição**, e usarmos "itens que o Grupo Impr. estiver preenchido", **a frase está incorreta.**